# Re-render element for component in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have created a component with `tagName: 'video'` which is rendered into a template.

After performing specific operations on the `video` element, it can enter a non-functioning state, which requires a re-render restore.

It is possible to do this re-render from the parent template by removing and re-inserting the component.
However, I want to do it from the component itself, which I think is possible.

I have tried to call `this.rerender()` from the component, however this did not work.

Comment: Have you tried toggling the isVisible property on the component, might force a re-render but not sure

Comment: Can you paste your component code?

Comment: `isVisible` doesn't remove the element.